# 500 Internal server in lighttpd while calling CGI written in "C"

Tags: webserver, embedded-linux, lighttpd

The server is Linux and running lighttpd
The test code in "C" is like below (test.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
 printf ("Welcome to CGI");
return 0;
}
```

I compiled the code to generate CGI like below

```
gcc test.c -o test.cgi
```

I put the generate test.cgi file in web/cgi-bin/ folder and it showing following error while accessing it fron browser /cgi-bin/test.cgi

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

The log file consists of

```
2021-01-04 04:56:32: (../../lighttpd-1.4.53/src/response.c.628) Path         : /filesys/web/cgi-bin/test.cgi
2021-01-04 04:56:32: (../../lighttpd-1.4.53/src/response.c.652) -- logical -> physical
2021-01-04 04:56:32: (../../lighttpd-1.4.53/src/response.c.653) Doc-Root     : /filesys/web/
2021-01-04 04:56:32: (../../lighttpd-1.4.53/src/response.c.654) Basedir      : /filesys/web/
2021-01-04 04:56:32: (../../lighttpd-1.4.53/src/response.c.655) Rel-Path     : /cgi-bin/test.cgi
2021-01-04 04:56:32: (../../lighttpd-1.4.53/src/response.c.656) Path         : /filesys/web/cgi-bin/test.cgi
2021-01-04 04:56:32: (../../lighttpd-1.4.53/src/response.c.668) -- handling physical path
2021-01-04 04:56:32: (../../lighttpd-1.4.53/src/response.c.669) Path         : /filesys/web/cgi-bin/test.cgi
2021-01-04 04:56:32: (../../lighttpd-1.4.53/src/response.c.676) -- handling subrequest
2021-01-04 04:56:32: (../../lighttpd-1.4.53/src/response.c.677) Path         : /filesys/web/cgi-bin/test.cgi
2021-01-04 04:56:32: (../../lighttpd-1.4.53/src/response.c.678) URI          : /cgi-bin/test.cgi
2021-01-04 04:56:32: (../../lighttpd-1.4.53/src/response.c.679) Pathinfo     :
2021-01-04 04:56:32: (../../lighttpd-1.4.53/src/mod_access.c.177) -- mod_access_uri_handler called
```

Comment: Read much more about [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), e.g. [RFC7540](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540) and about [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface). Did you consider using [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) inside your web server, or coding some [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) application?

Comment: I tried using FastCGI, and ultimately will use that. For some basic requests wanted to use CGI also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by @basile-starynkevitch, your program output is not compliant with the (very simple) [CGI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875) protocol.  However, lighttpd will still handle that.

You did not share your lighttpd.conf (`lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf -p`), so I am guessing that you did not properly configure lighttpd [mod_cgi](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModCGI) to handle the request.

The user account under which the web server is running should have filesystem access to the path and files wherever your `web/cgi-bin/` is located.

If this has never worked for you, then also check to see if SELinux is blocking the CGI execution.

Comment: Thank you it helped, but in my case issue was with cross compilation and got resolved by doing so

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved, so posting the solution.
Basically, there is cross-compilation issue to execute in the target embedded device which was not compatible with GCC.